# Pamusb doesn't exist for some reason on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

So this is a weird issue im having. I tried to install `libpam-usb`, `pamusb-common`, and `pamusb-tools`. I used both `apt`, and `apt-get`. I just get the no package error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpam-usb
E: Unable to locate package pamusb-common
E: Unable to locate package pamusb-tools
```

I also updated everything and rebooted. Is it just under a different name, or is it deprecated? If it is, is there something else that works? Thanks.

Edit: I found `pam_tally`, and I have the same issues.

Edit#2: I found `Linux-PAM`, but even adding a device is undocumented. Its a mess, and there is no even remotely easy way to integrate it for a single user.

Answer (score 1):

The USB Pluggable Authentication Module project is **unmaintained** since more than a year.
[**Unmaintained** source of pamusb are on GitHub](https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb)

**But**, Someone (*Adrian Nöthlich*) has worked on making an PPA Package:
https://launchpad.net/~promasu/+archive/ubuntu/libpam-usb

Answer (score 0):

Even if this question is quite old, since it ranks high on search results I want to point out that an updated version of pamusb is available.

See https://github.com/mcdope/pam_usb/. There is also a repository with prebuilt packages available.